# Most efficient method to import bulk JSON data from different sources in postgresql?

Tags: json, import, copy, bulkcopy, postgresql-13

I need to import data from thousands of URLs, here is an example of the data:

> [{"date":"20201006T120000Z","uri":"secret","val":"1765.756"},{"date":"20201006T120500Z","uri":"secret","val":"2015.09258"},{"date":"20201006T121000Z","uri":"secret","val":"2283.0885"}]

Since COPY doesn't support JSON format, i've been using this to import the data from some of the URLs:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE stage(x jsonb);

COPY stage FROM PROGRAM 'curl https://.....';

insert into test_table select f.* from stage,
   jsonb_populate_recordset(null::test_table, x) f;
```

But it is inefficient since it creates a table for every import and it imports a single url at a time.
I would like to know if it is possible (through a tool, script or command) to read a file with all the URLs and copy their data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) and [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql) for this task.

spyql can convert JSON lines (1 json file per line) into bulk INSERT statements. Since your json is an array we will use jq to transform it into JSON lines format.

**1st step: JSON to JSON lines using jq**

```
$ jq -c ".[]" sample.json 
{"date":"20201006T120000Z","uri":"secret","val":"1765.756"}
{"date":"20201006T120500Z","uri":"secret","val":"2015.09258"}
{"date":"20201006T121000Z","uri":"secret","val":"2283.0885"}
```

**2nd step: JSON lines to bulk INSERTs using spyql**

```
$ jq -c ".[]" sample.json | spyql -Otable=table_name "SELECT json->date, json->uri, json->val FROM json TO sql"
INSERT INTO "table_name"("date","uri","val") VALUES ('20201006T120000Z','secret','1765.756'),('20201006T120500Z','secret','2015.09258'),('20201006T121000Z','secret','2283.0885');
```

**3rd step: pipe the INSERTs into the DB**

```
$ jq -c ".[]" sample.json | spyql -Otable=table_name "SELECT json->date, json->uri, json->val FROM json TO sql" | psql -h my_host -U my_user my_db
```

Disclosure: I am the author of spyql.